# How to properly configure xdebug.client_host for Docker in Linux?

Tags: php, linux, docker, xdebug, wsl-2

I am running a PHP server inside a Docker container on Linux (WSL2). I would like to connect Xdebug to this process, but can't find out which IP to use for this.

On Windows and Mac, the `xdebug.idekey=host.docker.internal` variable automatically maps the correct IP, but AFAIK this isn't available in Linux.

I've tried manually inputting the IP from `ip show route` and `hostname -I` from both the host as well as the docker-container, but these don't work either (and would only be a temporary fix even if they did work).
My container also does not have a `docker0` network, which some tutorials want to use to connect, and I am not sure what that is or how I get one.

**So the question is:** how can I get the correct IP address and automatically set it in my configuration (docker-file, docker-compose or php.ini file)

Comment: Check comments in https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58539029/geting-the-private-ip-for-the-docker-network-from-within-the-container-to-config. There are multiple recipes there. For example: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264#issuecomment-763555307 or the last one: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264#issuecomment-772844305 -- seems to work in latest versions, just add those 2 extra lines.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have since gotten the static `ip route show` to work. The connection was being blocked by the Windows firewall (thanks to WSL...). However, i am still unable to find a more general solution. The one explained in the github link does not seem to work for me. I replicated the docker-compose file and set up the phpstorm project, but am not getting a connection through `host-gateway`. replacing `host-gateway` with the current ip does work.

Comment: I see. My fault, sorry. In such case those links will not help you. For some reason I thought it's just Docker on Linux and skipped the WSL2 part completely. So you are actually on Windows. Do you run a Docker inside the WSL2 (manually installed docker there inside WSL2 image)  ... or is that you are using Docker Desktop for Windows and using WSL2 as a backend engine for the Docker (instead of HyperV)?

Comment: Maybe i should have made that clearer. There are so many cogs involved, i'm not sure which ones are relevant where... i'm running docker desktop in windows, using the WSL2 based engine. I thought that equates to having docker run inside linux (?)

Comment: AFAIK the `host.docker.internal` should be working then. I may suggest to check https://www.pascallandau.com/blog/setup-phpstorm-with-xdebug-on-docker/ , https://medium.com/@tomasbruckner/intellij-xdebug-with-wsl-2-docker-4224b6efb0bb , https://www.silverf0x00.com/setting-up-xdebug-for-phpstorm-on-windows-wsl2/

Comment: Ah sorry. I am using PHPSTORM inside WSL2... basically everything is in WSL2, except for docker which is using the wsl2 engine but is installed on windows

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to set the correct IP address and automatically set it to your configuration files.

- Make sure your firewall is deactivated between Windows and WSL

```
# Windows powershell as administrator
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "WSL" -Direction Inbound -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)" -Action Allow
```

- Add this line to your `~/.bashrc` in WSL

```bash
export host_ip=$(ipconfig.exe | grep 'vEthernet (WSL)' -A4 | cut -d":" -f 2 | tail -n1 | sed -e 's/\s*//g')
```

- You can verify your IP with

```bash
echo $host_ip
```

Now you can use your new variable everywhere.
eg in `.env` file`:

```bash
XDEBUG_CONFIG="client_host=${host_ip} remote_port=9003 idekey=PHPSTORM"
```